# Do you need to cast to data.frame in order to convert rownames before casting to tibble

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, tibble

I use a gene expression package that outputs a named matrix. In order to get this into a tibble, I always have to first cast it to a `data.frame` so that I can then convert the rownames. Is there a shorter way of doing this? eg:

```
library(tidyverse)
normalized_counts %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>%
  rownames_to_column('name') %>%
  gather(key = experiment, value = expression, -name) %>%
  as_tibble()
```

Where I would much prefer to do something like:

```
library(tidyverse)
normalized_counts %>% 
  as_tibble() %>%
  rownames_to_column('name') %>%
  gather(key = experiment, value = expression, -name)
```

But I can't because I loose the rownames at the `as_tibble` step.

Comment: It is better you provide a small reproducible example.  What is `normalized_counts`?  Is it a matrix ?  If that is the case, `tibble` or `data_frame` strips off the row names and have a default row number as row names where as `as.data.frame` keeps the row names as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`as_tibble` has a rownames arugument you can use.

```
library(tidyverse)
normalized_counts %>% 
  as_tibble(rownames = 'name') %>%
  gather(key = experiment, value = expression, -name)
```